# Is there any simple way to save data beside creating live usb?

Tags: windows-xp, backup

My windows laptop has a problem. It actually has problem with its battery, somehow the battery is not functioned anymore. This morning, my 18 month boy turned on the laptop without any power plugged in. Then the laptop is turned on for a while after that it turned off automaticallt, because of the battery. Then my wife is going to work with that windows laptop, but it seems that the OS is not booting properly and it always restart after a few seconds displaying the windows xp loading logo. This problem give a headache to my wife, because she didn't backup yet her data.
If it is about OS only issue, this issue will be resolved by installing new windows. But I don't have the installation disc. Second, my friend said that if I boot using live usb, you may save the data from the harddisk. Umm..this one also need download first the iso.
What I want to ask, is there any simpler way to save data beside above options?

In my mind, if I can run DOS from usb (*in my opinion, downloading portable dos would be easier maybe), and I can access the harddisk to save the data.
Is this possible? Please give advice.

Comment: Regarding your booting up problem, getting a new battery should fix it.  I had the same situation. Even when plugged in, if the battery is completely dead, the laptop wouldn't startup properly.

Comment: Plain old DOS won't help you without jumping through hoops, since it has no in-built NTFS or USB support. There are plenty of [small Linux distros](http://superuser.com/a/520254/138343) though if download size is an issue.

Comment: How about making a LiveCD?

Comment: For a minimal fee you can order recovery CD from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another PC take the hard drive out, and buy and external enclosure hook the hard drive up to it.  Plug the enclosure into the other PC and the drive letter should appear and let you copy files from it.